# Substring search on multiple attributes

Tags: php, object-oriented, sql, mysql

```
    public function getData ($term) {
        $db = Database::getInstance();

        $term = htmlentities($term);

        //Kill the script if the term is blank
        if ($term == "") {
            die();
        }

        $query = "SELECT * FROM coils WHERE name like '%$term%' or 
                                            resistance like '%$term%' or 
                                            wraps like '%$term%' or
                                            wire_one like '%$term%' or
                                            wire_two like '%$term%' or
                                            wire_three like '%$term%' or
                                            wire_four like '%$term%' or
                                            wire_five like '%$term%' or
                                            wire_six like '%$term%' 
                                            LIMIT 25";
        $prepareQuery = $db->getConnection()->prepare($query);
        $result = $prepareQuery->execute();
        $this->rowCount = $prepareQuery->rowCount();

        //Return the Query
        return $prepareQuery;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create full text search indexes for these fields and use MATCH ... AGAINST

This way you can change this line to:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM coils MATCH ( name, resistance, wraps, wire_1, wire_2, wire_3, wire_4, wire_5, wire_6) AGAINST ('$term') LIMIT 25";
```

**Updated:** If you want stick to string substitution when mounting your `$query` (like you did), make sure you have sanitized your `$term` variable in order to prevent SQL injection attacks. But it's **highly recommended using** `bind` **solution** nicely expanded below by @greg-burghardt.

More information about MATCH AGAINST can be found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Comment: Are there recommendations for sanitation of variables or is just `htmlentities` enough? I've read that the `prepare()` function sanitizes input for me.

Comment: Prepare can do the job safely. I sticked to your pattern (which I consider wrong) just to make my example easies to understand. If you want to change, you need to bind valeus after prepare statement and before executing it. see here:  http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Couldn't this get messy real fast? I have a query that inserts about 15 columns of data and I feel that using `bindParam` could make my code very mess, very fast.

Comment: On the contrary, concatenation can mess your code quickly and it is much more prone to strange errors. PHP bind is a neat solution because it accepts named parameters, making things more clear. When you keep your statements separated from binds, you add clarity to code reading and you make it a lot safer. And after all, there are things you can't do easily through concatenation (for example: try to search for "McDonald's", which is a valid company name in a database)

Answer (score 2):

- The method name is `getData`, which is a very generic name, and something like `getCoilsByTerm` would be better. As a side question, what is the name of the class to which this method belongs? Knowing that can help us come up with a better name.
- The `$result` variable is assigned, and then never used. To make things even more confusing, you are returning the `$preparedQuery` object instead. Wouldn't it make more sense to return the results of the query? Plus, it would be easy to parameterize the `limit` as well:

  ```
  public function searchCoils($term, $limit = 25) {
      if (empty($term)) {
          throw new Exception('Term cannot be empty');
      }

      $db = Database::getInstance();
      $query = "SELECT * FROM coils
                MATCH (
                  name,
                  resistance,
                  wraps,
                  wire_1,
                  wire_2,
                  wire_3,
                  wire_4,
                  wire_5,
                  wire_6
                ) AGAINST (:term)
                LIMIT :limit";
      $statement = $db->getConnection()->prepare($query);
      $statement->bindParam(':term', $term);
      $statement->bindParam(':limit', $limit);

      return $statement->execute();
  }
  ```
- Lastly, don't call `die()` if the `$term` is empty. It's OK to halt the execution of the program, but give Future Joe Scotto a little help in debugging the failure: throw an exception with a sensible message.

Edit: I expanded upon @DavidRissatoCruz's MATCH AGAINST query.

Comment: When running `MATCH AGAINST` in my database I'm getting this error: `The used table doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes.`

Comment: So I fat fingered the add comment button on the android app and added my comment as an answer. I don't have the permissions to delete it. But, what data types are each of the columns in the query?

Comment: The data types are `TEXT`